# How to get a thread name in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, identifier

I'm trying to get **the thread name `test_thread`** with **`threading.current_thread().name`** between **`t.start()`** and **`t.join()`** as shown below:

```py
import threading

def test():
    print("test")
                                  # Thread name                  
t = threading.Thread(target=test, name="test_thread")
t.start()
print(threading.current_thread().name) # Here
t.join()
```

But, I got **`MainThread`** instead of **`test_thread`** as shown below:

```
test
MainThread # Here
```

So, how can I get **the thread name**?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **`threading.current_thread().name`** in **`test()`** as shown below:

```py
import threading

def test():
    print("test")
    print(threading.current_thread().name) # Here
                                                              
t = threading.Thread(target=test, name="test_thread")
t.start()                         # Thread name
t.join()
```

Then, you can get **`test_thread`** instead of **`MainThread`** as shown below:

```
test
test_thread # Here
```

In addition, if you use **`t.name`** out of **`test()`** as shown below:

```py
import threading

def test():
    print("test")
                                                              
thread = threading.Thread(target=test, name="test_thread")
t.start()                              # Thread name
t.join()
print(t.name) # Here
```

You can get **the thread name `test_thread`** as shown below:

```
test
test_thread # Here
```